# Moving a div after another has been moved using if statement

Tags: jquery, css, if-statement

I basically have a set of notifications stacked in a list which each can be removed individually, thus sliding out of the notification container.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

 $('.closeAlert1').click(

    function(){ $('.alert1').css({left: '500px'}) }


)

});
```

When a notification is closed, whether it's the first or the fifth, I need to notifications that haven't been removed to rise to the top of the container to fill the space that the now removed notification had left.

I've tried using something like this which didn't seem to work

```
if( $(".alert1").css('left') == '500px') {

$(".alert2").css('top','0px');

}
```

If anyone could give me some advice, I've attempted to use the first code above but It generally only works if someone closed them in the order of 1-2-3-4 rather than someone closing them like 2-1-4-3.

thanks

Comment: What does your html look like?

Comment: Are these elements being dynamically added? How many alerts do you have? You should think about providing a common class to all close or alert elements for a reusable event listener and then adding ids or data attributes to determine which element to affect.

Comment: Your problem could be, that you don't free the space a notification occupied with hiding/removing the element. You can have a look at this [example](https://jqueryui.com/hide/) with the `slide` effect

Comment: Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/p0q687wg/) something you would like to achieve?

Comment: @empiric I've really gone about doing my html the wrong way with the notifications, this seems to make far more sense, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple. Just add to all alerts same class "removableAlert" and remove it this way:

```
$(function() {
  $(".removableAlert").click(function() {
    $(this).animate({left: "+=500"}, 400).slideUp();
  });
});
```